# Is it possible to put the flex sdk onto a web server and reference it locally?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sdk, webserver, external

I want to try and build a project locally with my project pointing to an external sdk (via webserver.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this it would likely drastically increase your compilation times so I'd not recommend trying.

Comment: Alright, now what if I compile locally and then put it on my server to reference the sdk from the server?

Comment: @Dennis - That sounds more like a runtime shared library (rsl) on your server than an sdk.

Comment: Ah yes yes, I've been doing some research and that is exactly what I found. Thanks!

Comment: In Flex 4, all the Flex framework files are loaded by default as .swz files from Adobes server, and if the connection fails, then it looks for the local (your web server version) of these files. If you do an Export Release Build, and look in bin-debug, you will see these files